# Javascript date.toLocaleString() Producing Incorrect Results For EST

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I run the following script with node (v16.6.2)

```js
const src = new Date("8/13/2021, 8:00:00 PM");
console.log(src.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "PST"
}));
console.log(src.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "CST"
}));
console.log(src.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "EST"
}));
```

I receive the following output:

```
8/13/2021, 6:00:00 PM
8/13/2021, 8:00:00 PM
8/13/2021, 8:00:00 PM
```

(For reference I live in central time).

Obviously, Central Time is correct, and Pacific Time prints out correctly as well. However, Eastern Time is always printing out Central Time outputs, instead of the expected 9:00 PM output.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: There is no guarantee that an implementation will know what "EST" is. In fact, in Firefox, I get an error that "PST" is not a valid time zone. You might have more luck with time zones of the format "America/New_York"

Comment: It also works correctly for me if I use `US/Pacific`, `US/Central`, and `US/Eastern`